# Implications of incorrectly configured subnet mask / gateway

Tags: networking

I have recently done an upgrade on a Cisco 2520. As part of the upgrade and SVI was added to the switch to allow a VLAN to route locally which was previously done at another switch (via a trunk). The SVI had the following parameters;

Network Addr: 192.168.65.96
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.248
SVI Addr: 192.168.65.102

There were two devices on this subnet and, when the the change was made both devices were still able to communicate to the remote network even though the default gateway and subnet mask were 192.168.65.1 / 255.255.255.0 respectively.

Subsequent to this, while monitoring, I lost communications to one of the devices however the other remained online. I rectified the problem by correctly configuring the Subnet Mask and Default gateway on both devices but I was wondering if anyone could explain why I was able to communicate with one device and not the other even though both devices had incorrectly configured sunet masks /default gateways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Netmasks (subnet masks) aren't part of the IP address and don't go anywhere in the IP header; a packet addressed to "192.168.65.96" is still addressed to "192.168.65.96" no matter the netmask used.

Instead, netmasks work as a form of *routes*, and they're only used when sending packets, but not when receiving – i.e. a host with a wrong netmask configured will still be able to receive packets but may be unable to send them correctly.

When sending packets, the netmask is checked to determine **whether the destination IP address is in the same subnet** as the sending host:

- If both the source and the destination are in the same subnet, then that means it's possible to send packets directly at MAC level ("layer 2") *without using a gateway*, and the sender will use ARP to directly resolve the IP address to the receiver's MAC address.

  So if both hosts are within the same subnet (according to each other's netmask), then it doesn't matter if the gateway address is misconfigured because a gateway is not needed in that situation.
- If they're *not* in the same subnet, then a gateway is required, and the sender will use ARP to find the gateway's MAC address instead.

So a misconfigured netmask will only affect communications with those addresses for which it gives wrong results to the "Same subnet?" test.

- If your netmask is **too broad** (prefix length too short) and covers more addresses than it should, then you will no longer be able to send packets to the addresses that the netmask accidentally includes (but which aren't actually "local" to your subnet).

  When trying to send packets to such addresses, your host will try to resolve them via ARP as if they were local, even though they aren't, i.e. the ARP requests won't reach them.

  For example, if you are in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, but accidentally configure your netmask as /16 (255.255.0.0), you will lose communications with the rest of 192.168.x.x (although you'll still be able to reach 192.168.1.x as before).

  (Though communications *may* still be possible if your gateway implements 'Proxy ARP' and answers those ARP requests on behalf of the "other side" – this is actually sometimes done by ISPs as 'client isolation', or as an interim step in splitting up a large subnet. Indeed Proxy-ARP was used to split large classful networks before subnetting was invented.)

  Either way, you'll still be able to communicate with local hosts that are actually in your subnet, as well as remote hosts that the wrong netmask doesn't cover, so this may go unnoticed for a while.
- If the netmask is **too narrow** (prefix-length too long) and doesn't cover addresses that it should, then you have the opposite result – you might not be able to communicate with the part of your subnet that the netmask accidentally excludes, because your host thinks it needs to go through a gateway for those addresses.

  If there *is* a gateway, then it may just route packets back to the same subnet, and things will still work – just very inefficiently. The gateway might also send you ICMP "Redirect" packets, informing you that a more direct path exists, and your OS might automatically update its routing table to allow for direct communications again. So the misconfiguration may go unnoticed for a very long time.

  But if the netmask is too narrow *and* the gateway is wrong, then you won't be able to send packets to those addresses at all – your host will try to direct them through the nonexistent gateway.

In both situations, the only affected destinations are those for which the 'correct' and 'wrong' netmasks give different results.